# Using selectableItemBackground with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, but I am not sure how I would add it into a `ConstraintLayout` where I already apply a background colour to the `TextView`. This is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout for app main screen -->
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        android:text="@string/category_numbers"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/family"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_family"
        android:text="@string/category_family"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numbers" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

With a `LinearLayout`, I know I can use `FrameLayout` and nest the `TextView` inside where I can apply `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` and `android:background="@color/category_numbers"` to the `FrameLayout`. This can then be repeated for each of the `TextView` within the layout. However, when I try this for the `ConstraintLayout` it is unable to render.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "unable to render"? what is stopping you from doing the same thing you did, with a `ConstraintLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`? i.e. putting `TextView` in a `FrameLayout` and putting `FrameLayout` in a `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @Weizhi, yes that was the way. Just didn't take into account the circular constraint handles would disappear when using the FrameLayout object. Got so used to clicking and dragging them into position :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured the problem. Under the `LinearLayout` all the `FrameLayout` would just stack when using `android:orientation="vertical"` within the `LinearLayout` opening tag. When using `ConstraintLayout`, I needed to add constraints to the left, right and top for each of the `FrameLayout` so that they stack the same as the `LinearLayout`.

If anyone is interested here is the XML for `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

    <!-- Numbers category -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numbers"
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="@string/category_numbers" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Family category -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/category_family">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/family"
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:text="@string/category_family" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the XML for `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout for app main screen -->
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        android:id="@+id/frameNumbers"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numbers"
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:text="@string/category_numbers" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- Family category -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frameFamily"
        android:background="@color/category_family"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameNumbers"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/family"
            style="@style/CategoryStyle"
            android:text="@string/category_family" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For some reason as soon as I used FrameLayout the circular constraint handles would disappear.